# .html() ignores new lines in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm experiencing some cross-browser compatibility issues.

My web page contains a text area and a DIV. User input from text area must be replicated to DIV.

```
this.$highlighter.html(text);
```

this line is being executed every single time user presses a key. *$highligter* is a DIV and variable "text" contains user input. It works fine if user is typing normal text. But if user hits enter to create a new line - new line is being ignored, and does not appear in DIV but only for IE8. It works perfectly fine for >=IE9 and all other browsers. Any ideas?

I'm using jQuery 1.8.3

Comment: yes, idea is to stop optimizing for dinosaur browsers.

Comment: http://theie8countdown.com/ Take a quick look, this should help.

Comment: I do know that you are going to say that guys, but its not up to me to decide to drop IE8 support for company product :)

Comment: Sorry, I am using only modern browsers, so I can't debug IE. In fact, I don't give a damn about IE at all, my idea is that if people use bad browser, they get bad experience.

Answer (score 0):

Since IE 8 creates a lot of problem you can try multiple solutions.

- First Method: Use empty() & then set html using html()

  $('Element ID OR Class').empty().html(string);
- Second Method is to try using append() instead of html().

  $('Element ID OR Class').empty().append(string);
- This is very unlikely of what you want but you can give it a try

  document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = data;

I hope any of these methods help.